# regex to limit string and trim/leading spaces

Tags: reactjs, regex

I have a regex text for check length of string :
Anychar between 2 and 40 chars.

```
const texte = RegExp(/^.{2,40}$/, 'g')
```

The problem is, if I set double spaces, regex match (normal).
But I want to specify my regex don't match for trim and trail spaces.
How can I do that please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the length limit to ignore trailing/leading spaces , try this regex:

```
/^\s*\b.{2,40}\b\s*$/
```

- `^` start of the string
- `\s*` match any spaces
- `\b` word boundary
- `.{2,40}` any character length between 2 and 40
- `$` end of the string

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/d8RC0g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^\s*\S.{0,38}\S\s*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKo4lE/1/).

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `\s*` - 0+ leading whitespaces
- `\S` - a non-whiespace
- `.{0,38}` - zero to 38 chars other than line break chars
- `\S` - a non-whiespace
- `\s*` - 0+ trailing whitespaces
- `$` - string end.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like this?

```
const texte = RegExp(/^[^ ]{2,40}$/, 'g')
```

Comment: This fails non-trailing/leading spaces(e.g. `hello world`)